# gdata.data.PhoneNumber: How do I get the type of Phone Number?

Tags: google-api, gdata, google-api-python-client

Using the class gdata.data.PhoneNumber, how do I get the type (Home/Business/Mobile/etc.) of that phone number?

This is the documentation I am referencing: https://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/pydocs/gdata.data.html#PhoneNumber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "rel" attribute should be what you are looking for.
This is example code from https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client/blob/master/tests/gdata_tests/contacts/service_test.py:

```
# Create a new entry
new_entry = gdata.contacts.ContactEntry()
new_entry.title = atom.Title(text='Elizabeth Bennet')
new_entry.content = atom.Content(text='Test Notes')
new_entry.email.append(gdata.contacts.Email(
    rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work',
    primary='true',
    address='liz@gmail.com'))
new_entry.phone_number.append(gdata.contacts.PhoneNumber(
    rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work', text='(206)555-1212'))
new_entry.organization = gdata.contacts.Organization(
    org_name=gdata.contacts.OrgName(text='TestCo.'), 
    rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work')
```

It doesn't access the "rel" attribute but it is there, I swear :)

Once you get a PhoneNumer instance you can print every attribute with [the built-in dir() function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir):

```
print(dir(phone_number))
```

The following is a list of "rel"s (https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client/blob/master/src/gdata/data.py). I don't know whether all are applicable to phone numbers or not but it may be useful for checking the type:

```
FAX_REL = 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#fax'
HOME_REL = 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home'
HOME_FAX_REL = 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home_fax'
ISDN_REL = 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#isdn'
MAIN_REL = 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#main'
MOBILE_REL = 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#mobile'
OTHER_REL = 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other'
OTHER_FAX_REL = 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other_fax'
PAGER_REL = 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#pager'
RADIO_REL = 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#radio'
TELEX_REL = 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#telex'
TTL_TDD_REL = 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#tty_tdd'
WORK_REL = 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work'
WORK_FAX_REL = 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work_fax'
WORK_MOBILE_REL = 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work_mobile'
WORK_PAGER_REL = 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work_pager'
NETMEETING_REL = 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#netmeeting'
```

Those OTHER "rel"s can (or maybe should?) be joined with the object's "label" attribute.